# Create a table with a column that has 2 concatenated values from different columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

How to create a table that has one column that it's value is a concatenation of two values from multiple columns in the same table?

For example - The table "users" has the following columns -
**id**, **name**, **last_name**

How can I create this table in **Postgresql** so every time I insert a new row, the value of the "**id**" column is generated by concatenating the "**name**" and the "**last_name**" column values?

Is there such functionality when declaring DEFAULT value on the column?

The end goal is to create this table using SqlAlchemy ORM (When the values would be generated in the SQL server and not logically in the sqlalchemy framework).

Comment: "*the value of the "id" column is generated by concatenating the "name" and the "last_name" column values*" - this is a really bad idea. The "ID" column supposedly should be a primary (or at least unique) key. Which will never work if you just concatenate name and last_name. Just define the primary key as an `identity` column

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yeah it's ok.. It was just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres now supported generated columns, so you can add such a column as:

```
alter table users add full_name varchar(255) 
    generated always as (name || ' ' || last_name);
```

Note that I did **not** add this as the id but as a new column.  The `id` should be a number so it can be used efficiently for indexes and foreign key references.

In addition, you should *never* put PII into primary keys.  That just proliferates privacy issues throughout the entire database.

Comment: What is a PII? Also what is the problem of having the id as a string? You can still create indexes on string columns, no?

Comment: @Drxxd . . . PII = Personal Identifiable Information.  It is the subject of many laws in many jurisdictions these days.